# Use different configs depends on spring active profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to have different spring configurations depending on active spring profile. If i start jar with --spring.profiles.active=blabla i use one config, and if no profile in start arguments i use another. Now i can use blabla profile, but if i start jar without profiles it uses both.

Default config:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
                HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
                SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@Slf4j
public class DefaultConfig {

    public DefaultConfig() {
        log.error("Using default config");
    }

}
```

Blabla config:

```
@Profile("blabla")
@Configuration
@Import({
        DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class,
        ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        JacksonAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
})
@Slf4j
public class BlablaConfig {

    public BlablaConfig() {
        log.error("Using bla bla config");
    }

}
```

Now:

java -jar app.jar:

```
...
Using default config
Using bla bla config
...
```

java -jar app.jar --spring.profiles.active=blabla:

```
...
Using bla bla config
...
```

Shoud be:

java -jar app.jar:

```
...
Using default config
...
```

java -jar app.jar --spring.profiles.active=blabla:

```
...
Using bla bla config
...
```

Comment: can you show the `application.yml` or `application.properties` which has all these profiles

Comment: "*if no profile in start arguments i use another*" "*if i start jar without profiles it uses both*" These two statements appear to contradict one another. When you start with no profiles, do you want one or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@Profile("!blabla")` to your `DefaultConfig`.

Comment: ty, thats what i need